# SwiftUI - Using Multiple Enums with a single picker view to select option

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using Enums to provide choices for pickers in my app and I created a custom picker wheel to deal with those choices. This is how the picker wheel looks currently for a string array of options:

```
struct Settings_SegmentedPickerView: View {

    @State var settingName: LocalizedStringKey
    @State var itemsToPick: [String]
    @Binding var selectedItem: Int

    var body: some View {
       Picker("", selection: $selectedItem) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< itemsToPick.count) { index in
                        Text(self.itemsToPick[index])
                            .tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                
    }
}
```

and my implementation of the view is:

```
@State private var selectedItem: String = ""
 Settings_SegmentedPickerView(settingName: "Name of Setting", itemsToPick: ["Option One", "Option Two", "Option Three"], selectedItem: $selectedItem)
```

However, I want to use an enum like this to provide the options:

```
enum Choices: String, Equatable, CaseIterable {
    case none = "none"
    case one = "one"
    case two = "two"
    case three = "three"
    
    var displayName: String {
        switch self {
        case .none: return "New Option None"
        case .one: return "New Option One"
        case .two: return "New Option Two"
        case .three: return "New Option Three"
            
        }
    }

var someOptions: [ActionsDataChoice] {
        return [.none, .one]
    }
    
    var id: String { return self.rawValue }

}
```

And set up the view like this:

```
@State private var selectedItem: Choices = .none
 Settings_SegmentedPickerView(settingName: "Name of Setting", itemsToPick: Choices.allCases, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
```

Is there any way to modify the code of my view so I can pass in any enum of all cases/subset of cases defined in enum var, and it will set the picker to all the options/subset of options defined in the enum, and set the variable based on the enum case selected in the picker? Can this be achieved via a generic type of some kind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use same view to edit different enums with binding in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771477/use-same-view-to-edit-different-enums-with-binding-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your **Settings_SegmentedPickerView** to make it more generic and accept any enum that conforms to the CaseIterable protocol

```
    struct Settings_SegmentedPickerView<T: CaseIterable & Equatable & Hashable, V: View>: View {
@Binding private var selectedItem: T
let settingName: LocalizedStringKey
let itemsToPick: [T]
let labelProvider: (T) -> V

init(settingName: LocalizedStringKey, itemsToPick: [T], selectedItem: Binding<T>, labelProvider: @escaping (T) -> V) {
    self.settingName = settingName
    self.itemsToPick = itemsToPick
    self._selectedItem = selectedItem
    self.labelProvider = labelProvider
}

var body: some View {
    Picker(settingName, selection: $selectedItem) {
        ForEach(itemsToPick, id: \.self) { item in
            labelProvider(item).tag(item)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}}

var body: some View {
    Picker("", selection: $selectedItem) {
        ForEach(itemsToPick, id: \.self) { item in
            labelProvider(item).tag(item)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}}
```

Now The **Settings_SegmentedPickerView** takes two generic parameters: T represents the enum type, and V represents the view type used to display each option in the picker. The labelProvider closure is used to provide the view representation for each enum case.

you can then use this with your Choices enum:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
@State private var selectedItem: Choices = .none

var body: some View {
    Settings_SegmentedPickerView(settingName: "Name of Setting", itemsToPick: Array(Choices.allCases), selectedItem: $selectedItem) { choice in
        Text(choice.displayName)
    }
}}
```

I have updated Choices Enum by conforming it to Hashable

```
    enum Choices: String, Equatable, CaseIterable, Hashable {
case none = "none"
case one = "one"
case two = "two"
case three = "three"

var displayName: String {
    switch self {
    case .none: return "1"
    case .one: return "2"
    case .two: return "3"
    case .three: return "4"
    }
}}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Do the T and V need to be those specific letters, or are these values that can I can pick (and T and V are just common in this usage)?

Comment: Also, when I put this code into my file, I get an error: Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<T>' to type 'State<T>'

This happens on the  self._selectedItem = selectedItem

Comment: @BenjaminB. Here's the updated code that addresses the errors you mentioned.
If this answer resolves your question, kindly mark it as accepted

Comment: you crushed it, ty so. much for your help and such a thorough answer :)

Comment: can you 2x check and edit your solution, I think the code for the view is duplicated in the Settings_SegmentedPickerView struct...